# Java.lang.Illegal State Exception: The specific child already has a parent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting following exception when implementing the code below the exception.

Java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specific child already has a parent. you must call the removeView() on the child's parent first.

```cs
using System;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.App;

namespace Recycle.Droid
{

    internal class albumadapter1 : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        // private int[] imageid;
        // private Photo_album palbum;
        // private _Recycler _Recycler;
        private int[] imageid;
        private Activity mainActivity;

        public albumadapter1(Activity context, int[] imageid)
        {
            this.mainActivity = context;
            this.imageid = imageid;
        }
        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get
            {
                return imageid.Length;
            }
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            PhotoViewHolder vh1 = holder as PhotoViewHolder;
            vh1.img.SetImageResource(imageid[position]);
            //vh.Caption.Text = palbum[position].Caption;
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            var itemview = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_holder, parent);
            PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemview);
            return vh;
        }
    }
    public class PhotoViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        public TextView tv { get; private set; }
        public ImageView img { get; private set; }

        public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {

            img = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            //  var Caption = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
            // public PhotoViewHolder(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)

        }
    }
}
```

please help me with problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add False to the code below your issue will be solved

.......
...
...
..
.
 public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            var itemview = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_holder, parent, false);
            PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemview);
            return vh;
        }
.....
...
..
.

Comment: it worked for me ,can you explain the selection of an particular image from the path and send it to the recyclerView,as i have the uri( address of selected item)  as  i assigned it to a variable ,while binding iam getting the complete images of that directory i need the single item that exsisting in uri; help me.